# l10n called before initState

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Found a problem regarding Flutter's handling towards l10n and `void initState()`.

l10n works well pm it's own. Does the job but I found a particular scenario which I thought should be labelled.
I'll be more specific by showing an [example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/bottom_navigation_demo.dart).
The following code has been taken from the [gallery app](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/bottom_navigation_demo.dart):

```
...
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _navigationViews = <NavigationIconView>[
      NavigationIconView(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
        title: 'Alarm',
        color: Colors.deepPurple,
        vsync: this,
      ),
      NavigationIconView(
        activeIcon: CustomIcon(),
        icon: CustomInactiveIcon(),
        title: 'Box',
        color: Colors.deepOrange,
        vsync: this,
      ),
      NavigationIconView(
        activeIcon: const Icon(Icons.cloud),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.cloud_queue),
        title: 'Cloud',
        color: Colors.teal,
        vsync: this,
      ),
      NavigationIconView(
        activeIcon: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
        title: 'Favorites',
        color: Colors.indigo,
        vsync: this,
      ),
      NavigationIconView(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.event_available),
        title: 'Event',
        color: Colors.pink,
        vsync: this,
      )
    ];

    _navigationViews[_currentIndex].controller.value = 1.0;
  }
...
```

I'm struggling using localisation within the `initState` function.
You can (somewhat) bypass this by using the user's language code and translate it manually instead of using a `locales.dart` file, neither less I assume this is an ongoing problem that should be addressed.

NOTE: As I was writing this post I've thought about an idea to bypass this by calling the l10n strings from a former class - testing this theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up "passing down" the values from a former class. This "problem" can be resolved by using ether InheritedWidget or "passing down values".

Comment: `didChangeDependencies` might also work if `initState` does not work.

Comment: This is a solution towards any other example apart from the [gallery app (bottomnavbar) example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/bottom_navigation_demo.dart).